# C# XmlException because of file name

Tags: c#, xml, exception

I am working on a launcher/updater for a game. the updater get's it's data from an xml file on a server. Up til now my code (Which has a few references from other's code) has worked just fine. I tested it and it downloaded the files just fine, however, the files I used to test it were jpg's. The actual files the launcher will need to download are a series of characters, eg: (e}xP7,iIlM7Q8=&@vR2-sv~]9.5
when downloading these it throws an exception every time. I'm not great with C# so I thought I'd ask for help in the place where I always find my answers. ;)

Sample of my XML:

```
<theupdates>

<update>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <file>(e}xP7,iIlM7Q8=&@vR2-sv~]9.5.$}t]8</file>
    <path>http://test.m-containers.com/Updates/</path>
  </update>

  <update>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <file>;V;xP,S]PXKr8;{(8HO2NJ H-g;PAo_yTuIV</file>
    <path>http://test.m-containers.com/Updates/</path>
  </update>

<update>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <file>^_HZpQ;Xpi{QS`Ku,}@#B}JYW}Q+;gdO0</file>
    <path>http://test.m-containers.com/Updates/</path>
  </update>

<update>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <file>{G'A4l7O8]~nb(a!mrK5hE)o</file>
    <path>http://test.m-containers.com/Updates/</path>
  </update>

</theupdates>
```

Sample of my c# code:

```
    string Root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

    XDocument serverXml = XDocument.Load(@"http://test.m-containers.com/Updates/Updates.xml");
    foreach (XElement update in serverXml.Descendants("update"))
    {
        string version = update.Element("version").Value;
        string file = update.Element("file").Value;
        string path = update.Element("path").Value;


        string sUrlToReadFileFrom = path + "V" + version + "/" + file;

        string sFilePathToWriteFileTo = Root + "\\Resource\\" + file;

        Uri url = new Uri(sUrlToReadFileFrom);
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();

        Int64 iSize = response.ContentLength;

        Int64 iRunningByteTotal = 0;

        using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            using (System.IO.Stream streamRemote = client.OpenRead(new Uri(sUrlToReadFileFrom)))
            {
                using (Stream streamLocal = new FileStream(sFilePathToWriteFileTo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    int iByteSize = 0;
                    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[iSize];
                    while ((iByteSize = streamRemote.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        streamLocal.Write(byteBuffer, 0, iByteSize);
                        iRunningByteTotal += iByteSize;

                        double dIndex = (double)(iRunningByteTotal);
                        double dTotal = (double)byteBuffer.Length;
                        double dProgressPercentage = (dIndex / dTotal);
                        int iProgressPercentage = (int)(dProgressPercentage * 100);

                        Downloader.ReportProgress(iProgressPercentage);
                    }

                    streamLocal.Close();
                }

                streamRemote.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to have it, basically, not throw a tantrum when it reads these characters or perhaps, likely more reasonable, a better way to go about this?

I appreciate any insights anyone can offer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to have it, basically, not throw a tantrum when it reads these characters or perhaps, likely more reasonable, a better way to go about this?

Yes. Make it a valid XML file. This isn't valid XML:

```
<file>(e}xP7,iIlM7Q8=&@vR2-sv~]9.5.$}t]8</file>
```

The `&` should be `&amp;`.

My guess is that the server isn't using a proper XML API to generate the XML - it's just writing out text in a dumb fashion. Never do that. When manipulating XML, *always* use an XML API so it will handle this sort of thing for you.

You *shouldn't* have to fix this on the client - why should everything reading this data accommodate a broken writer? It's not clear whether you're in control of the server code (in which case you should fix it) or whether it's third party code (in which case you should shout at them, very loudly). Either way, advertising something as XML when it blatantly isn't is just a bad idea.